# Kaluza-Klein dimensional reduction with Kalb-Rammond field present

Tags: gauge-theory, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

When looking at sources on KK dimensional reduction, usually only the metric and/or the vielbein are discussed.

However, if we have other fields present, especially p-forms, then there arise some problems/subtleties, I have not seen dealt with.

Take the example of the Kalb-Ramond field, i.e. a 2-form field $B$ over D+1 dimension, transforming under 1-form symmetries, i.e. $\delta B = d\theta$, with $\theta$ a 1-form.
If we find adapted coordinates $(x^\mu, z)$ where $\mu=0,...D-1$, we can define $A_\mu := B_{\mu z}$ and $\lambda := \theta_z$ and find that after dimensional reduction we have
$$
\delta A_\mu = \partial_\mu \lambda \\
\delta B_{\mu \nu} = (d\theta)_{\mu \nu}.
$$
So $A$ becomes a U(1) gauge field, while $B$ (from now on always meaning $B_{\mu \nu}$ over D dimensions) carries the remainder of the 1-form symmetry.
Now the interesting part happens when we consider the remainder of the diffeomorphisms, given by vector fields $(\xi^\mu, \xi^z) $ acting via the Lie derivative. As is well known, the $z$-component of these appear as a kind of U(1) symmetry, with the corresponding U(1) gauge field $C_\mu$, s.t. $\delta C_\mu = \partial_\mu \xi^z$.

A small calculation then shows that (switching to index free notation)
$$
\delta(\theta, \xi^z) B = d\theta + A \wedge d\xi^z,
$$
meaning that the $\xi^z$ transformations mix components of $A$ into $B$.
Now if we do KK dimensional reduction to get a particle theory from a string theory, then the particle cannot couple to $B$, only to $A$. So we would like to set $B=0$, but then we immediately find the condition that
$$
d \theta = - A \wedge d\xi^z .
$$
Differentiating that equation again, we finally get the condition that
$$ 
F(A) \wedge d\xi^z = 0.
$$
So my question is, what the consequences of the last two equations really is?
The second one is surely satisfied if either $A$ is flat, i.e. $F(A) = 0$ or $\xi^z$ is constant. Both are conditions that constrain in which way our U(1) symmetries can present.

Thanks in advance